# For storing short, many, bilateral messages, should I use JSON instead of Mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, json, database

I'd heard that the main flaw of using json for storing messages is that it's easily corrupted when someone tries to modify message and the other writes and pushes into that message stock at same time.

But I'm not considering to give permission of modifying or deleting message to users. Neither to myself.

And since the message system which I'm about to develop will be fit to send or receive short, many messages in brief moment, I don't want my db table get locked down.

In this case, can I use static json file to store messages instead of db? Please recommend other good methods, if you think this is clumsy idea.

Comment: instead of saving them to db , define them in your one file with some constant and use that constants accordingly. Almost all frameworks are using that pattern. You can check any of them for reference. Or you can  search it on google also. you can get lot of tutes regarding that

Comment: Your question, as written, is somewhat comparable to asking: "When I get hungry, should I eat some meat, or should I eat with a fork?"  Wait, what?  The question isn't really about JSON... it's about storing something in a file instead of in a database.  "Should I use XML instead of MySQL?" is the exact same question, and both seem based on a flawed premise that writing files to the local disk is infinitely scalable.  It seems like you should be using a queue.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thank you man, It helped me alot!